# Bounded Derivative implies $\|F(x_1)-F(x_0)\|_{\infty} \leq C \|x_1-x_0\|_{\infty}$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to prove the lemma below. I'm supposed to use Mean Value Theorem and the inequality $\|S \circ T\|\leq \|S\|\|T\|$ that holds for linear and bounded operators $S$ and $T$.

> Let $U\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ is open and $F:U \to \mathbb R^d$ is differentiable at all points of $U$. If $x_0$ and $x_1$, together with all the points on the line segment connecting them, belong to $U$ and if $\|F^{\prime}(x)\|\leq C$  holds at each point $x$ on this line segment, then $\|F(x_1)-F(x_0)\|_{\infty} \leq C \|x_1-x_0\|_{\infty}$ ($\infty$ norm is maximum of components)

Here is what did I do :

$h(t)=x_0+t(x_1-x_0)$ and $\varphi(t)=(f_i\circ h)(t)=f_i(x_0+t(x_1-x_0)) $ where $f_i$s are components of $F$.

By MVT for real valued functions with single variable,

$\exists a\in (0,1)$ such that $\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)=\varphi^{\prime}(a)$

$\Rightarrow \ \ f_i(x_1)-f_i(x_0)=f_i^{\prime}(x_0+a(x_1-x_0)).(x_1-x_0)\qquad ...(*)$

**1** I know that LHS of $(*)$ is real valued but I am not sure RHS of the equation. I think the dot must be inner product. If yes how can I obtain it by chain rule?

**2** I don't know where should I use $\|S \circ T\|\leq \|S\|\|T\|$ for getting inequality.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $f_i'(x_0+a(x_1-x_0)$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^{d}$ to $\mathbb R$. In (*), $f_i'(x_0+a(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_0)$ stands for the value of this transformation at the point $x_1-x_0$. And $|f_i'(x_0+a(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_0)| \leq \|f_i'(x_0+a(x_1-x_0)\|\|x_0-x_0\|$. Can you complete the proof now?